# SQL - How to multiple join

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables: table1, table2, table3, table4. table1 contains id values related to all other tables (2,3,4) and I would like to connect all of them to have all data in one set, I think it's simple relation.

I tried this, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table1'
JOIN 'table2' ON 'table1.id_forT2'='table2.id'
JOIN 'table3' ON 'table1.id_forT3'='table3.id'
JOIN 'table4' ON 'table1.id_forT4'='table4.id'
WHERE 'table1.id' = 30
```

When I left only one join it works fine, with 2 or 3 joins it returns an error. How to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just that your ticks aren't in the right place.   And is this MySQL?  Because then you want back-ticks instead of single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.id_forT2=`table2`.id
JOIN `table3` ON `table1`.id_forT3=`table3`.id
JOIN `table4` ON `table1`.id_forT4=`table4`.id
WHERE `table1`.id = 30
```

Comment: Of course, you are right! My ticks weren't in the right place, now it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of two reassons:

1. Quotes/Backtips: Maybe you aren't using this properly
2. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`: Perhaps one table has no data for the relation

You should specify if you're using `mySQL`, `postgreSQL` or other.